# Ionic : how to use Infinite Scroll for displaying contact list

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I am using Ionic4 . I am trying to display the phone contact list but the loading time for the list is too slow. I want to use Infinite Scroll but its not working . I am new in ionic so please help me .
My html file code :

```
   <ion-content padding >
      <ion-searchbar (keyup)="SerachContact($event)" ></ion-searchbar>
      <ion-list  *ngFor="let contact of contactlist; let i = index;" >
      <ion-item >
      <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <div>
            <ion-icon ios="ios-person" md="md-person"></ion-icon> <b>  {{contact.displayName}}</b>
          </div>
        </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col  size="10">
          <div>
            <ion-icon item-start  ios="ios-call" md="md-call" ></ion-icon> {{ contact.phoneNumbers[0].value}}
          </div>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
    </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

 <ion-infinite-scroll threshold="100px (ionInfinite)="onInfiniteScroll($event)">
        <ion-infinite-scroll-content
          loadingSpinner="bubbles"
          loadingText="Loading more data...">
        </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
      </ion-infinite-scroll>

    </ion-content>
```

and my ts file code :

```
import { Component, OnInit ,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Contacts, Contact, ContactField, ContactName } from '@ionic-native/contacts/ngx';

import {  NavController,IonInfiniteScroll} from '@ionic/angular'; 

import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.page.scss'],
  providers: [Contacts],
})

export class ContactPage implements OnInit {

 @ViewChild(IonInfiniteScroll) infiniteScroll: IonInfiniteScroll;

  ngOnInit() {
  } 

 contactlist: any[];   

   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private router: Router, 
     private contacts: Contacts , public callNumber: CallNumber ) {

      this.contacts.find(["displayName", "phoneNumbers"], {multiple: true}).then((contacts) => {
        this.contactlist = contacts;
          this.contactlist.sort(function(a, b) {
             return compareStrings(a.displayName, b.displayName);
          });  
      });
}

onInfiniteScroll(event) {
      setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Done');
      event.target.complete();
      if (data.length == 1000) {
        event.target.disabled = true;
      }
    }, 500);    
}
```

How can I use Infinite Scroll for fast display . please give some idea. Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess that when you refer that the "loading time for the list is too slow", is because the list have many items. So you need to do is that for example retrieve only the first 10 item, and when infiniteScroll fire an event (I mean that scroll until down), you need retrieve the next 10 items, obviously need to have variables to control the count of items to know which items are next and when you got all items to disable the infiniteScroll.

Comment: any example please